# Rule/pattern about using loan words for monarchs?

Tags: loanwords

We call the monarchs of Germany, Russia and Ancient Egypt "Kaiser", "Tzar/Czar" and "Pharaoh" respectively, but the monarchs of France, Spain, China and Japan "king" or "emperor".  Is there any sort of pattern or rule about when loan words are used or not for monarchs, or is it just random?

Comment: If it's English, it's random.

Comment: For "king" or "queen," maybe it has to do with whether the role itself was synonymous, because Britain, France, and Spain used to follow a feudal system that was similar to one another and different than the systems of Germany and Russia.  As for "emperor," that denotes colonization, ruling over territories outside the homeland itself, that also puts said "emperor" over a king or queen or equivalent.

Comment: By the way, when we call, for example, the sovereign of Portugal "king" instead of "rei," that's called an "exonym" -- just a bit of trivia as a sort of antithetical term for your usage of the term "loanword" (i.e., When we apply an exonym instead of a loanword to the sovereign of a country...).

Comment: Another tidbit that relates to your question but is off-topic in regard to its answer has to do with the word "pharaoh."  "Pharaoh" was a figurehead term that was also usually the political leader, but not always. We use the word "king" to denote the ancient leader of Egypt who was really in charge during periods in which the pharaoh was not the political leader. That generally only happened when the pharaoh was a woman, unless, like Cleopatra VII, she killed her younger brothers so she could be the political leader, too, which is why Cleopatra VII is sometimes referred to as Pharaoh Queen.

Comment: She gets called that to point out that she wasn't just pharaoh but also queen, meaning she wasn't just a figurehead like was normally the case when the pharaoh was a woman.  We don't hear that with male pharaohs because no male pharaoh was ever just a figurehead but always ruled as the all-powerful leader as well.

Comment: Why do we use terms like *prefecture*, *oblast*, or *governorate* when we could just label everything a *province*? Why say *diet*, *thing*, or *duma* when *parliament* would do? Or to get away from politics, why say *Paris Métro* when the *Paris Underground* or *Paris Subway* would be adequately understood? The answer is that you could— and in fact Peter the Great elevated himself from *Царь* to *Император*, so *Emperor* is arguably more accurate. The localized terms provide precision, or exoticism under the pretense of precision.

Comment: Not to do with the English language, the original words are used where they exist and are more popularly understood, and native (of the language of the writing in question) words where they don't or are not widely known.

Comment: @Billy That sounds very close to an answer (as much as can be given for English). Can you make it one?

Comment: I think most of it just comes down to tradition and the timing of when we started referring to the heads of various states, similar to whether we use anglicized names of the countries and people themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because of how recently we have been referring to them.
The English have been 'dealing' with the kings of France and Spain (or Castille and Aragon) for a 1000 years and so the same word was used as for their native leaders.

German Kaisers and Russian Czars are a more modern introduction and had a novelty value. Similarly Pharaohs would only have come into common use with Victorian archaeology.

Comment: And Asian words for king or emperor weren't imported because native English speakers found them difficult to pronounce?

Comment: They were used at the time, Victorian literature is full of Sheikhs and Nabobs (even if not used accurately) and the whole of Gilbert and Sullivan is the novelty of the titles of eastern potentates